# Postgres not using GiST index in lateral join

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Here is the setup:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS A;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS B;

CREATE TABLE A(shape Geometry, id INT);
CREATE TABLE B(shape Geometry, id INT, kind INT);
CREATE INDEX ON A USING GIST (shape);
CREATE INDEX ON B USING GIST (shape);
```

I am running the following commands:

```
ANALYZE A;
ANALYZE B;

EXPLAIN
  SELECT * FROM (SELECT A.id as aid, (SELECT B.id FROM B WHERE
     ST_Contains(B.shape, A.shape)
     AND B.kind != 1 LIMIT 1) as bid FROM A) AS TMP;
```

which gives me

```
      {
    "Plan": {
      "Node Type": "Seq Scan",
      "Relation Name": "A",
      "Startup Cost": 0.00,
      "Total Cost": 2606592.33,
      "Plan Rows": 549745,
      "Plan Width": 1646,
      "Plans": [
        {
          "Node Type": "Limit",
          "Parent Relationship": "SubPlan",
          "Subplan Name": "SubPlan 1",
          "Startup Cost": 0.00,
          "Total Cost": 4.68,
          "Plan Rows": 1,
          "Plan Width": 8,
          "Plans": [
            {
              "Node Type": "Seq Scan",
              "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
              "Relation Name": "B",
              "Startup Cost": 0.00,
              "Total Cost": 4.68,
              "Plan Rows": 1,
              "Plan Width": 8,
              "Filter": "((shape && A.shape) AND _st_contains(shape, A.shape))"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Note that there is a sequential scan inside the lateral join, however there is clearly an index available. However after setting

`set enable_seqscan=false;`

the index is being used. This actually affects runtime significantly and seems that postgres should figure things like that automatically.

```
 {
    "Plan": {
      "Node Type": "Seq Scan",
      "Relation Name": "A",
      "Startup Cost": 10000000000.00,
      "Total Cost": 10004716493.85,
      "Plan Rows": 549450,
      "Plan Width": 1677,
      "Plans": [
        {
          "Node Type": "Limit",
          "Parent Relationship": "SubPlan",
          "Subplan Name": "SubPlan 1",
          "Startup Cost": 0.00,
          "Total Cost": 8.52,
          "Plan Rows": 1,
          "Plan Width": 8,
          "Plans": [
            {
              "Node Type": "Index Scan",
              "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
              "Scan Direction": "NoMovement",
              "Index Name": "B_shape_idx",
              "Relation Name": "B",
              "Startup Cost": 0.00,
              "Total Cost": 8.52,
              "Plan Rows": 1,
              "Plan Width": 8,
              "Index Cond": "(shape && A.shape)",
              "Filter": "_st_contains(shape, A.shape)"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
     }
    }
```

Is there any way to tell postgres to use index in a less hacky way? Possibly by rewriting the query? From what I understand the use of `set enable_...` is not recommended in production.

### NOTE

When you actually run the commands above it will give

```
{
    "Plan": {
      "Node Type": "Seq Scan",
      "Relation Name": "a",
      "Alias": "a",
      "Startup Cost": 0.00,
      "Total Cost": 10372.75,
      "Plan Rows": 1230,
      "Plan Width": 36,
      "Plans": [
        {
          "Node Type": "Limit",
          "Parent Relationship": "SubPlan",
          "Subplan Name": "SubPlan 1",
          "Startup Cost": 0.14,
          "Total Cost": 8.41,
          "Plan Rows": 1,
          "Plan Width": 4,
          "Plans": [
            {
              "Node Type": "Index Scan",
              "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
              "Scan Direction": "NoMovement",
              "Index Name": "b_shape_idx",
              "Relation Name": "b",
              "Alias": "b",
              "Startup Cost": 0.14,
              "Total Cost": 8.41,
              "Plan Rows": 1,
              "Plan Width": 4,
              "Index Cond": "(shape && a.shape)",
              "Filter": "((kind <> 1) AND _st_contains(shape, a.shape))"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Unfortunately I cannot provide data to reproduce the query plan results.

Comment: Please, include output of `EXPLAIN (analyze, buffers)` instead.

Comment: `, (SELECT B.id FROM B WHERE
     ST_Contains(B.shape, A.shape)` Why this subquery instead of `a join b on st_contains(... )` ?

Comment: @wildplasser because I need only one row of table b for each row in a and the execution should stop when one is found